# Django Contact Form TypeError: context must be a dict rather than Context

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am experiencing an error "context must be a dict rather than Context." upon submitting a contact form. I have a hunch that it's due to incompatibility issues with Django 1.11. Not too sure how to find a workaround.

Here is what I'm getting on the traceback:

http://dpaste.com/18T2D2V

```
Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact/

Django Version: 1.11.3
Python Version: 3.6.0
Installed Applications:
['collection',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'registration']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']

Traceback:

File "/Users/billphan/Desktop/Projects/hello-web-app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/billphan/Desktop/Projects/hello-web-app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/billphan/Desktop/Projects/hello-web-app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/billphan/Desktop/Projects/hello-web-app/collection/views.py" in contact
  95.             content = template.render(context)

File "/Users/billphan/Desktop/Projects/hello-web-app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  64.         context = make_context(context, request, autoescape=self.backend.engine.autoescape)

File "/Users/billphan/Desktop/Projects/hello-web-app/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/context.py" in make_context
  287.         raise TypeError('context must be a dict rather than %s.' % context.__class__.__name__)

Exception Type: TypeError at /contact/
Exception Value: context must be a dict rather than Context.
```

Here's my code snippet for the contact route in my views.py file:

```
def contact(request):
form_class = ContactForm

# new logic!
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = form_class(data=request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        contact_name = form.cleaned_data['contact_name']
        contact_email = form.cleaned_data['contact_email']
        form_content = form.cleaned_data['content']

        # email the profile with the contact info
        template = get_template('contact_template.txt')

        context = Context({
            'contact_name': contact_name,
            'contact_email': contact_email,
            'form_content': form_content,
        })
        content = template.render(context)

        email = EmailMessage(
            'New contact form submission',
            content,
            'Your website <test@gmail.com>',
            ['youremail@gmail.com'],
            headers = {'Reply-To': contact_email }
        )
        email.send()
        return redirect('contact')

return render(request, 'contact.html', {
    'form': form_class,
})
```

This is apparently the line that's causing the error:

```
content = template.render(context)
```

Not so sure how to workaround this, seeking some guidance! Thanks!

Comment: Just FYI this was a change introduced in 1.11: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.11/#django-template-backends-django-template-render-prohibits-non-dict-context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing

```py
context = Context({
    'contact_name': contact_name,
    'contact_email': contact_email,
    'form_content': form_content,
})
```

with

```py
context = {
    'contact_name': contact_name,
    'contact_email': contact_email,
    'form_content': form_content,
}
```

Comment: That totally did the trick! Such a small fix and couldn't wrap my head around it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you create your context, just create a dictionary, not a `Context` object.

```
context = {
            'contact_name': contact_name,
            'contact_email': contact_email,
            'form_content': form_content,
          }
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks Zach!